# Views: show nodes that share taxonomy term with user

Tags: 7, users, views

I have a content type `requests` with the taxonomy field `categories`.  I have added `categories` to my user's profile as well.

I need to create a view that displays all the requests that have category terms the user has selected in their profile.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view showing requests.
2. Add a contextual filter for Field: Category.
3. When the filter value is NOT in the URL choose "Provide default value" of type PHP.
4. In the "PHP contextual filter code" write:

---

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
return $account->field_category['und'][0]['tid']; // this line may need changing based on your category field name
```